# Multi-line Button cut-off after two lines in Menu

Tags: swiftui

I have created a simple `Menu` which I want to use to display a hint to the user. In the menu, I add a `Button`.
<sub>(if I add a `Text` directly, its text color turns gray, so this is a workaround. The button doesn't do anything, though).</sub>

```
Menu {
    Button { } label: {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.")
    }
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
}
```

This results in the following:

[image: menu with text cut-off]

As you can see, the text is cut-off after two lines. If I move the button outside the menu, it properly shows three lines of text. Also, if I replace the `Button` with just `Text`, I get the same issue. Same goes for using `Label` instead of `Text` inside the button.
I have already tried modifiers like `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`, or `.lineLimit(nil)` without any luck.

Does anyone know how I can work around this height limitation?

Comment: I recommend a custom View for that Apple APIs are so rigid and limited.

Comment: I'll fallback to something custom, if necessary, yes. But things like `Menu` are so easy to use and I'd like to not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Yes, but the current wheel does not turn for you because it is square you need a circular wheel.   :)

Comment: Good point. I'm just often thinking I might've missed something. I'll wait & see if someone points it out or I need to accept the inevitable.